# SQL REGEXP_COUNT '.'

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking to count the number of full-stops/periods in a string; however, when using REGEXP_COUNT '.', it seems to count the number of characters in the string. I've tried replacing '.' using the asci version of '.' but it behaves the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
select regexp_count('a.b.c', '[.]')
```

Note that `.` is a wildcard in regular expressions that matches almost any character (I don't think it counts newlines by default).  The square brackets treat it as the period character.  You can also use a backslash.

Comment: A normal `.` doesn't count newlines unless you tell it too with the `n` [match parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/REGEXP_COUNT.html).